# A Java and PHP application

Tags: java, php

Is it possible to build a Java web application which has a PHP front end ?

I want all my web pages to be coded in PHP. Most of them will be forms.

I want all the data submitted by a form to go to a Java Code.

I want to do all manipulation in back end and all rendering of web content on the front end.

This is just a general question as I was probing for different options for my java web application.

Comment: According to your edit, do you understand the difference between PHP and **HTML** ? Looks like you don't need PHP at all, because "web pages" can be coded in HTML only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your edition, it looks like you don't need PHP at all. You confused it with HTML.

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to take a look at [php-java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/)

Answer (score 2):

A web application, by definition *is* already a frontend (or at least includes it).

If you meant a PHP webapp built on top of a Java backend, sure, that's possible. If you use SOAP or REST for communication between the layers, it's actually relatively easy. The only drawback compared to a pure Java (or pure PHP) app would be the overhead of those protocols, so you have to be careful to avoid too fine-grained service interfaces.

Comment: I want a simple integration. Is it not possible for the data submitted by php forms to be captured and manipulated by a simple java web application code ??

Comment: @Anand: there's no such thing as a PHP form. It sounds like you want in fact a Java webapp without any PHP at all.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where the two meet. You could have, for example, have Java backend and PHP frontend communicating via web services. I however see no benefit in such a combination.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/quercus-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp#Java/PHP%20integration), a Java implementation of PHP, to run PHP from within Java (and thus have easy access to Java classes).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can build a java web-application which has php front end.

Answer (score -1):

it is possible even with C++ backend. but why?